# search string in comma separated array php

Tags: php

I need to return the array which contains the search string in the range .
Basically i want to search for string with pakistan1 and do not take above that that is it should ignore the array with key 0
second string bangladesh4 it should ignore any other keys below 4
Final return array should be

```
array(
[2]=>
[3]=>
[4]=>
)
```

There are two strings which needs to be searched. How I can go about ?

> First : pakistan2
>
> Second :  bangladesh4

```
$input_arr= array(
    0=>array(india0,srilanka1,pakistan0,banglades0),
    1=>array(india1,srilanka1,pakistan1,bangladesh1),
    2=>array(india2,srilanka2,pakistan2,bangladesh2),
    3=>array(india3,srilanka3,pakistan3,bangladesh3),
    4=>array(india 4,srilanka4,pakistan4,bangladesh4),
    5=>array(india 5,srilanka5,pakistan5,bangladesh5),
);
```

I want to return the resulting array as :

```
$result_arr= array(
    2=>array(india2,srilanka2,pakistan2,bangladesh2),
    3=>array(india3,srilanka3,pakistan3,bangladesh3),
    4=>array(india 4,srilanka4,pakistan4,bangladesh4)
)
```

**EDITED**

```
$first_str = "pakistan2";
$second_str = "bangladesh4";


$arr_output = array();
foreach($input_arr as $key=>$temp_arr)
{

    if(in_array($first_str, $temp_arr) || in_array($second_str, $temp_arr) )
    {
        $arr_output[$key]=$temp_arr;
    }
}
```

Not able to get
array 3

Comment: How 3 will come in result ?

Comment: can it be based on Index? for example pakistan 2 is found on key 2 and bangladesh4 is found in key 4.So is there any possibility of finding the string found from key 2 to key 4 including key 3 .?

Comment: i have written the code for you but question is on hold so not able to  post you here

Comment: @JigneshPatel And it should be on hold because a person has not even tried to do anything and just dumped his problem.

Comment: I changed the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$input_arr= array(
    0=>array("india0","srilanka1","pakistan0","banglades0"),
    1=>array("india1","srilanka1","pakistan1","bangladesh1"),
    2=>array("india2","srilanka2","pakistan2","bangladesh2"),
    3=>array("india3","srilanka3","pakistan3","bangladesh3"),
    4=>array("india 4","srilanka4","pakistan4","bangladesh4"),
    5=>array("india 5","srilanka5","pakistan5","bangladesh5"),
);

$first_str = "pakistan2";
$second_str = "bangladesh4";


$arr_output = array();
foreach($input_arr as $key=>$temp_arr)
{

    if(in_array($first_str, $temp_arr) || in_array($second_str, $temp_arr) )
    {
        $arr_output[$key]=$temp_arr;
    }
}

print_r($arr_output);
```

Comment: I also require  3=>array(india3,srilanka3,pakistan3,bangladesh3),

Comment: why? it has no `pakistan2` or `bangladesh4`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $result_arr= array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($input_arr);$i++)
    {
     if(in_array("searchstring",$input_arr[$i]))
      if(in_array("searchstring2",$input_arr[$i]))
        $result_arr = $input_arr[$i];
    }
```